# facebook log in on click

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I have the following code (javascript)

```
       <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId: '<?=$this->facebook->getAppID()?>', 
              cookie: true, 
              xfbml: true,
              oauth: true
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                loading();
                alert("test");
                window.location = throute + "login/index/fblogin";                
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
                window.location.reload();
            });

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
                if (response.status=="connected") {
                    alert("test");
                    window.location = throute + "login/index/fblogin";
                }
            });
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
              '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());       
      </script>
```

If user is not logged in on fb everything is fine.

My problem is that if the user is already logged in on fb he is automatically logged in on site when he access it. I need him to log after click on the "Login" button.

Ty for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize the FB-app when the user clicks your loginButton. I am guessing you are using [facebooks own loginbutton](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/), you don't need to do that.

```
('#loginButton').click(function(){
     FB.init({
          appId: '<?=$this->facebook->getAppID()?>', 
          cookie: true, 
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
    //the rest of the code follows here
});
```

What will happen is that if users are already logged in on Facebook, they will be logged in directly upon pressing your button.

If the user is not logged in on Facebook, the login-dialog will appear upon clicking on your button.